# get the size of a list in a property

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a class A which have a list of B elements.

In my A class i would like to add:

```
int size;
```

which will be valued with the number of B elements. So when I would call `myA.getSize()` I will have it.

Is it possible to map a count query with a single property in the hibernate mapping?

I don't want to load the list that is why i would like to add a size property.

Comment: btw, you have to mark answers as accepted, if they work for you (via the tick below the vote counter)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to map a count query with a single property in the hibernate mapping?

Yes, use a [formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column):

```
<property name="size" type="integer"
formula="( select count(a.getBs) from A a where a.id = aid )">
</property>
```

More examples in [Example: Various Mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html).

Comment: @Pascal: is it possible to do the same with JPA annotations?

Comment: @Roman Hibernate has a `@Formula` annotation but this is an extension to JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use **lazy=extra** on the collection. This is barely mentioned in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) and explained further [here](https://www.hibernate.org/315.html).

> Use lazy="extra" on collections for
>   "smart" collection behavior, i.e. some
>   collection operations such as size(),
>   contains(), get(), etc. do not trigger
>   collection initialization. This is
>   only sensible for very large
>   collections.